# Is it ok to use the same vHard disk on a dual boot machine

Tags: virtualbox

I have a funny situation where I want to use the same vHard disk on a dual boot machine. One running win7 and the other linux. Since the disk is in a seperate Hard disk booth OS will have a different path to access it.

Is it possible to work like this? I guess each vm will have a different xml pointing to the same vDisk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not advised.

You may end up corrupting the vDisk if you accidentally run both VMs at the same time.

Comment: that will never happen as only 1 is booted

Comment: for some reason when I booted teh vm inside linux, did some changes, saved state, hibernated and moved back to windows, the state is not maintained..